# Use Angular interceptor without next.handle

Tags: angular

as i understood from angular interceptors documentation that next.handle() executes tasks after the HTTP request is done , so i tried using the intercept method without the next.handle() to run code before the execution of the HTTP request

```
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            if (!this.connectivityService.networkStatus.connected) {
                return throwError({message: 'error returned from interceptor'});
            }

    }
```

is it possible to use angular interceptor without next.handle() ?

Comment: This way the http request will never occur, why don't you add it after the `if` block, or in an `else` block, so that when there's no problem, the request continues? The answer to your question as is, is "yes", you can skip `next.handle()` and then nothing will happen, but without more details or clarity we can't really give a good answer to this question.

Comment: could you explain in an answer ?

Comment: As detailed in my comment, no I cannot, because the question isn't clear. Could you explain better what you want to achieve? Why are you avoiding `next.handle`, what's the goal of this piece of code?

Comment: yes, what i want to do is prevent making a HTTP request if there is no internet connection

Comment: Ok, so in the future, the purpose of what you are doing is much more important than a broad question that follows from it. We call this the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I hope I helped :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the clarified problem from your comments is as follows:

```js
intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
            if (!this.connectivityService.networkStatus.connected) {
                return throwError({message: 'error returned from interceptor'});
            }
            next.handle();

    }
```

You call `next.handle()` in all non-error scenarios so that the http request continues if there's no error, but is interrupted by the error condition.

Your interceptor is part of a pipeline, a chain made of multiple steps, and you let the process move to the next step with `next.handle()`. This means that you can place code before `next.handle()` that needs to happen before the HTTP request, and you can place code after `next.handle()` that needs to happen after the pipeline has completed. If you don't call `next.handle`, the pipeline is interrupted and doesn't happen. You return a `throwError` observable so that that is the end of the pipeline. It looks a bit like this in the non-error scenario:

```
A {
  B {
    C {
      http happens
    }
  }
}
```

And like this in the error scenario:

```
A {
  B {
    returns error value
  }
}
```

If `B` were your interceptor, and `A` and `C` some other parts of the pipeline.